# Have unique Gravatars shown with ME3 missions page

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, me3missions

Currently, anyone who has completed a mission, no matter what rank that mission is, they are shown for completing it, regardless of how high their rank is.

For example, I have completed up to Rank 4, but am shown on the past 3 ranks as well.  To me, it seems implied that in order to get to Rank 4, you had to have completed Ranks 1-3 anyway.  I think this will make it look a bit cleaner especially when there are even more contestants, as the competition goes on.

---

For redundancy's sake, can we have it so only a unique Gravatar appears for the highest rank you earn?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @SamuelStandrin I think the implied question is that your gravatar should only appear in the highest completed rank.

Comment: AAAHHH, that makes more sense... However if you get to rank 6 do you get prizes for rank 5,4 and 3... if so then the avatar should be put on all missions just so people know the amount of people who are there, as readin '34' can sometimes feel smaller than 34 avatars in a line

Comment: The contest rules say *Each user is only eligible for* ***one*** *prize. There are two prize choices for each level. You have your choice of one of the prizes for the highest level you complete.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't have really strong feelings about this, but I'm tending towards "no", for the following reasons:

- Staying with the "mission" metaphor, you still have completed mission 3, even if you also completed mission 4 (with your suggested change, you couldn't even say "completed by" on http://me3missions.com/ anymore; I'm not sure what the alternative phrasing would be).
- Missions 1 & 2, where the amount of people is the largest, only show the most recent 18 completers anyway.
- The promo only runs for another week, so it's not like there will be tons and tons of gravatars to show.
- It would look somewhat weird if (as it would be with the numbers right now) only three people are shown in mission 3, but 13 people are shown in mission 4.
- Having your gravatar appear 4-6 times on a page seems like a nice additional way to acknowledge that you made it all the way through.